# Finding similar contact names within table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am performing data clean up and one of my tasks is to delete similar duplicate contacts.

EXAMPLE:

```
BILL CROSBIE, BILL CROSBY, BILL CROSSBY; or KRISTEN HARRIS, KRISTIN HARIS.
```

So, there is no exact rule, but by manually scanning this, I can tell that they are very similar and must be duplicates.

Can anyone, provide an example of how I can do this using SSIS.

I understand that I can use the fuzzy lookup, but it requires a reference table or a reference data that is correct and would then compare to the table that needs data cleanup. However, is there a possibility that I can use the script component tool in SSIS to use an alogirthm that gets the characters with most matches. What would that C# code look like?

I am new to using SSIS and don't have much experience. Or is there some sort of script I can create in MSSQL that can do this?

Comment: You can find duplicated values with SOUNDEX (not the best way, but works quite well with your very small sample), but how will you know which duplicate you wanna keep and which you wanna delete ?

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c76e/13

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SSIS Fuzzy Lookup component.  I would use your Contacts table as the reference input, and store the new index (effectively creating an output table). I would configure the component's Advanced page to allow multiple matches and reduce the Similarity threshold.

After executing I would query the new index table, examining the similarity and confidence scores.  Scores above a certain threshold (depends on your data) would indicate a duplicate.