# Finding the similar names in single large df in python using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to figure out the best way possible to align my dataset which contains "Company Names". My dataset is about 300k rows and 3 columns. I tried many methods so far including Fuzzywuzzy using

```
choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
>>> process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
    [('New York Jets', 100), ('New York Giants', 78)]
```

Now this code has two data sets and when I convert df[Name] into two and match with the above method the first one by default becomes 100% since the list is duplicate.

My exact code is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["Google","google.inc", "ddood"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["google","google"]})

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

get_match = []
for row in df.index:
    name1 = []
    name1.append(df.get_value(row,"Name"))
    for columns in df2.index:
        name2 = []
        name2.append(df2.get_value(columns,"Name") )
        matched_token=[process.extract(x, name2, limit = 2)[0][1] for x in name1]
        get_match.append([matched_token, name1[0], name2[0]])
df_maneet = pd.DataFrame({'name1': [i[1] for i in get_match], 'name2':[i[2] for i in get_match], 'Ratio': [i[0][0] for i in get_match]})

new_df = df_maneet[df_maneet.Ratio>95]
```

I am in doubt if the above is the best way to approach my problem. My end result should be all similar like companies making a group.

The below answer did not help as well
[finding-similar-contact-names-within-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543022/finding-similar-contact-names-within-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fuzzy logic for excel data -Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507193/fuzzy-logic-for-excel-data-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to create a list of values & get ratio for each value pair with `fuzz.ratio` then select rows greater than your threshold ratio.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["Google","google.inc", "ddood"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["google","Grrgle"]})

x = np.array(np.meshgrid(df.Name.values, df2.Name.values)).T.reshape(-1,2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x)

df3.columns = ['Name1', 'Name2']

df3['Ratio'] = [fuzz.ratio(*i) for i in map(tuple, x)]


print (df3[df3.Ratio > 75])

    Name1   Name2  Ratio
0  Google  google     83
```

---

Edit: Use [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) to get close matches for your values.

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

df = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': ['Alarm.com','Analytics inc.','Adaptiv',
                                   'AllState Insurance','Alarm co', 'Analytics', 
                                    'Adaptive', 'AllState Insurance Group']})

df1 = df['company_name'].map(lambda x: get_close_matches(x, df.company_name, n=2,
                                       cutoff=0.8)).apply(pd.Series).dropna()

print (df1)
                          0                         1
0                 Alarm.com                  Alarm co
2                   Adaptiv                  Adaptive
3        AllState Insurance  AllState Insurance Group
4                  Alarm co                 Alarm.com
6                  Adaptive                   Adaptiv
7  AllState Insurance Group        AllState Insurance
```

Comment: but my problem remained the same. Since the dataset is too big. 300,000 rows. It will take forever to get the possible matches and then filtering out with above 60% match.

Comment: @ManeetGiri You can try the numpy approach. It's faster.

Comment: MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-1dedf6a15668> in <module>()
      6 #df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["google","Grrgle"]})
      7 
----> 8 x = np.array(np.meshgrid(df['Global Customer Name'].values, df2['Global Customer Name'].values)).T.reshape(-1,2)
      9 df3 = pd.DataFrame(x)
     10 

MemoryError:

Comment: Memory error for only first 10k rows. I got a dataset of 300k

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.. But do you think my problem is that unique? I just have a single column of companies and want to cluster the similar names together. like Washington DC, Washingtondc, Washington D.C.

Comment: @ManeetGiri Maybe we can also try `.str` methods but using loops are very inefficient. If possible provide some sample data. It's hard to say without looking at the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183187/discussion-between-maneet-giri-and-abhi).

Comment: Hi Abhi,  you helped me with the above problem. Would you mind sharing a way to contact you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try exploring libraries like [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) and [fuzzyset](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzyset/)

You can try using it like below with your dataframes `df` and `df2`:

```
In [1070]: from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM
In [1076]: SM(None, df['Name'].iloc[0], df2['Name'].iloc[0]).ratio()
Out[1076]: 0.8333333333333334
```

Please explore [fuzzy-string-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383044/fuzzy-string-comparison) for more info.

Let me know if this helps.